# Are questions about a particular climbing grade on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

It seems to me that if [How to progress in rock climbing after grades v4 / 5.11+?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18145/how-to-progress-in-rock-climbing-after-grades-v4-5-11) is on topic then so is how to progress past V1, V2, ..., VN and that we are going to have a bunch of boring questions. I just asked if there is something special about V4: [Are there particular grades that indoor climbers often struggle with](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18226/are-there-particular-grades-that-indoor-climbers-often-struggle-with), but assuming V4 is not a special grade, I think a canonical question that deals with how to progress is in order.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is, it would be hard to answer that question without knowing where the OP was at, and the answer would be different is the OP was trying to get past say 5.6 or V0.

This meta post seems to be one of those where someone thinks that because it would be possible to ask a bunch of very similar questions, that the site will be flooded with them and then everybody drowns or the server runs out of space or something terrible happens.

I think we ought to go with the principle of YAGNI and just not worry about it.

Comment: Hi Charlie! I've been trying but can't quite figure out what YAGNI stands for. Would you do me a favor and spell it out in the answer? Thanks!

Comment: [You aren't gonna need it](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html)

Comment: Thanks @ab2! You learn something new every day at this site!!